# Change 2 DIVS Using JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm still very new to writing JS.
I want to be able to change 2 divs based on on option from a  tag.

i.e if some one selects the color red it will show 2 different divs with content about red.

Please see the code below.

Thankyou in advance!

```
<Select id="colorselector">
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   <option value="green">Green</option>
</Select>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
    $('#colorselector').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        
         
    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: `divs with content about red` is unclear. Your code suggests two divs with the `id` matching the `select` value.... An `id` must be unique. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a div as a container for your divs and create them

```
<Select id="colorselector">
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
   <option value="green">Green</option>
</Select>

<div id="content"></div> 

$('#colorselector').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#content').html('');    
        $('#content').append('<div>Div 1'+ $(this).val()+'</div>');    
        $('#content').append('<div>Div 2'+ $(this).val() +'</div>');    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern day frontend is heavily dependant on templating and rendering. To get into React/Vue/Angular, start with any simple templating library. Eg handlebars:

Your solution in handlebars:

```
<Select id="colorselector">
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
        </Select>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Include Handlebars from a CDN -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
<script>
  // compile the template
  var template = Handlebars.compile("<div> 'This can be anything eg <b>bold</b> text or selected value: {{content}}</div>");


$(function() {
    $('#colorselector').change(function(){
        $('body').append(template({ content: $(this).val() }))
         
    });

    
});


</script>
```